# How to use a variable in sqlite3 csv import via awk

Tags: bash, sqlite, csv, awk, import

I want to import a txt file (semicolon separated) in a sqlite3 database. Unfortunately there are a lot of spaces in the file, I have to remove first. So I used something like this:

```
sqlite3 -csv sqliteout.db ".mode list" ".separator ;" ".import '|./normalize.awk infile.csv' importtable"
```

The normalize.awk removes all the spaces and returns everything again. The pipe is used to read from the input and not from a file. That works fine so far. Since I want to use this in a shell script I would like to replace the "infile.csv" by a variable but I can't find a way to do this because the variable is not evaluated with the single quotes. So, this is not working:

```
infile="infile.csv"    
sqlite3 -csv sqliteout.db ".mode list" ".separator ;" ".import '|./normalize.awk ${infile}' importtable"
```

Can't I somehow see the solution/problem? Can anybody help?

Comment: That will substitute the shell variable as desired...

Comment: But why use `-csv` if you immediately change the mode to list?

Comment: You are completely right. No idea what was wrong with me. Sorry.

Comment: And also dumb me, the `-csv` was a relict I never removed. Thank you very much!